# SQL timestamp interval minus 7 days

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the last 7 days from my database

so far i have the following:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(is_complete) 
FROM module_activity 
WHERE user_id = 30  
      AND timestamp BETWEEN NOW() 
      AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) 
GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

However this gives me no result.

My table looks like this:

```
  # id, user_id, module_id, is_complete,      timestamp
    '1', '30',      '5',      '1',      '2014-08-31 00:00:00'
    '2', '30',      '6',      '1',      '2014-09-01 00:00:00'
    '3', '30',      '7',      '1',      '2014-09-02 00:00:00'
    '4', '30',      '8',      '1',      '2014-09-03 00:00:00'
    '5', '30',      '9',      '1',      '2014-09-04 00:00:00'
    '6', '30',      '10',     '1',      '2014-09-05 00:00:00'
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSSQL documentation on the between statement:

```
test_expression BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

The first value (begin_expression) is supposed to be the lower value, and the second value (end_expression) is supposed to be the upper value. E.g. `col BETWEEN 1 AND 3`

Your statement has the lower and upper bounds the wrong way around, e.g. you have `col BETWEEN 3 AND 1`. This is the same as writing `WHERE col >= 3 AND col <= 1` which can never be true, which is why you do not see any rows.

You need swap the order of the lower value (i.e. now - 7 days) and the higher value (i.e. now)

```
timestamp BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: This behaviour is defined by the SQL standard though, so should be the same for all conforming database engines.

Comment: Although, if the DBMS supports it, you can use `x BETWEEN SYMMETRIC y AND z` to make the clause order insensitive. The default is to assume asymmetric.